# Is it ok to just have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Tags: jquery, ipad, responsive-design

I have a `960px` wide website and I managed to make it responsive for mobiles. So my styles apply for devices under `767px` and its looking good on mobiles and small tablets.

Then iPad `portrait` came to play. Its looking good on `landscape` but not on `portrait` as long as I have `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">` in header.

Then I created different jquery `events` to check `portrait`and change the `viewport` but everytime, i get some issues.

This is what I have so far. But the code isnt my question. My Question is, is ok to just leave `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in the header and I tested on iPad, iPhone, android, samsung, kindle fire (on simulator) and they seem to work fine now. So Im wondering do i NEED to have `initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1`?

My code that doesnt really work well.

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

if(isiPad){

    jQuery(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e) {
      switch ( window.orientation ) { 

        case 0: //port
        jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width');
        alert('1');
        break;

        case 180: //port
        jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width'); alert('2');
        break;

      }
     });

}
else if(!isiPad){
    jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use meta as in header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" >
```

You can do this in css using @media tags

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```